# How do you trigger a maker's infowindow using a dropdown menu using jquery in google maps api js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to control the markers using a dropdown outside the Google map. I know the dropdown works fine because it shows an error of google.

Below is my code.

```
var map;
var circleicon;

var infowindow, marker;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.415875, 123.107391),
    zoom: lastzoom,
    styles: [
          ...
        ]
  });

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                //var select_location = new selectLocation(locations[i][0]);
            }
        })(marker, i));

    }

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function(){
    console.log('zoom_changed');
    clearInterval(intID);

    var zoom = map.getZoom();

    if(zoom > lastzoom) {
        radiusMax /= 2;
        radiusMin /= 2;
        step /= 2;
    } else {
        radiusMax *= 2;
        radiusMin *= 2;
        step *= 2;
    }
    lastzoom = zoom;
  });

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
}


var map_location;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mapSelection").dropdown({
        onChange: function(val){
            map_location = val;
            google.maps.event.trigger(marker[map_location], 'click');
            alert(map_location);
        }
    });

});
```

Whenever I try to run again, I get an error 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined

Is there something wrong with how I initialize Google Maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you didn't create an array of markers but you tried to use a single marker as an array. I created `markers[]` array to prevent confusion, also you don't need another global variable for `marker`. `marker` it's scope is enough to trigger `infowindow`

**Working Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/ergec/smq8m547/

**Simplified JS Code**

I changed the code a bit to make it work, but you'll get the idea.

```
var map;
var infowindow, markers = [];

var locations = [
    ["blah", 33.808678, -117.918921],
    ["mehh", 33.807678, -117.928921],
    ["peww", 33.806678, -117.938921]
];

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                //var select_location = new selectLocation(locations[i][0]);
            }
        })(markers[i], i));

    }
}
initMap();

var map_location;

$(document).ready(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        $("select").append("<option value='" + i + "'>" + locations[i][0] + "</option>");
    }
    $("select").change(function() {
        var map_location = $(this).val();
        console.log(map_location);
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[map_location], 'click');
    });
});
```

Comment: I got the idea in placing the markers in an array.Thanks! It works great!